# Using transform to change the gameobjects postion etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

Hi I am trying to set my four walls of my video game aligned but I found doing that graphically to be time consuming so I tried creating a script and attaching it to a game object. Now in my book they talk about the transform component so I am using it to access the local position,rotation and scale of the player game object.

[The photo for reference of the walls is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxlAC.png)

The script is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemTransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SetScale(1.5f,30f,0.2f);
        SetPositoin(5f, -2.9f, -5.6f);
        SetAngle(215.611f, 6.513f, -88.83301f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void SetScale(float x,float y,float z)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
    void SetAngle(float x1,float y1,float z1)
    {
        transform.rotation = new Vector3(x1, y1, z1);
    }
    void SetPositoin(float x2,float y2,float z2)
    {
        Vector3 Position = new Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
        transform.position = Positon
    }
}
```

The error is

```
Assets\Scripts\LearningCurve.cs(12,12): warning CS0414: The field 'LearningCurve.CharacterAction' is assigned but its value is never used
```

Another error is

```
Assets\Scripts\ItemTransform.cs(31,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, 
decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Comment: You have a typo in `Positon` in line 31. Replace it by `transform.position = Position`. Regarding the warning, it's self-explanatory and should do no harm. In any case, the reported class code is not posted so we can't help with that.

Comment: Also missing a semicolon at the end of the typo'd `Positon`

Comment: Also, I highly doubt about setting `Vector3` value to rotation property =)

Comment: FYI your IDE should be screaming at you for all of these things. If it's not then you either need to enable Unity integration (Visual Studio, VS Code, etc.) or find a new IDE.

Comment: As @Morion suggests there are many reasons not to assign a vector directly to a rotation (too many for a comment - search for 'Unity Quaternions' for more info). Instead use `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x1, y1, z1);`

Comment: The learning curve warning is not an error. But a warning and no code is shown. But chances are. Its right.

Comment: Got it...yeah Ill check the whole IDE thing and uh gotcha on that Quaternions thing. Whoops sorry about the semicolon and naming problems those are basic errors also.

Comment: Hey @Morion is there a reason why dont directly set rotation to vector3 or is it just good practice not too

Comment: Rotation has `Quaternion` type, not `Vector3` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html.